# Filter out the input JSON based on the values and prepare the expected output using it

Tags: json, jolt

**Requirement:** Prepare the value for shipping amount field from the input JSON based on certain conditions, like below

1. If one of the elements of the input JSON has the value `DISTRIBUTION_CENTER` for `facilityTypeId`, then only prepare the `order ID` and `shipment ID`.
2. But if the elements don't have the value `DISTRIBUTION_CENTER` for `facilityTypeId`, then prepare the shipping `Amount`, from where the `orderAdjustmentTypeId` = `SHIPPING_CHARGES`, along with the `order ID` and `shipment ID`.

**Input JSON**

```json
[
  {
    "orderId": "16487",
    "orderAdjustments": [
      {
        "amount": 0,
        "orderAdjustmentTypeId": "DONATION_ADJUSTMENT"
      },
      {
        "amount": 15.95,
        "orderAdjustmentTypeId": "SHIPPING_CHARGES"
      }
    ],
    "shipments": [
      {
        "shipmentId": "0001",
        "shipmentItems": [
          {
            "parentFacilityTypeId": "PHYSICAL_STORE",
            "quantity": 1
          },
          {
            "parentFacilityTypeId": "DISTRIBUTION_CENTER",
            "quantity": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "orderId": "16488",
    "orderAdjustments": [
      {
        "amount": 10,
        "orderAdjustmentTypeId": "DONATION_ADJUSTMENT"
      },
      {
        "amount": 25.95,
        "orderAdjustmentTypeId": "SHIPPING_CHARGES"
      }
    ],
    "shipments": [
      {
        "shipmentId": "0001",
        "shipmentItems": [
          {
            "parentFacilityTypeId": "PHYSICAL_STORE",
            "quantity": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "orderId": "16489",
    "orderAdjustments": [
      {
        "amount": 10,
        "orderAdjustmentTypeId": "DONATION_ADJUSTMENT"
      },
      {
        "amount": 25.95,
        "orderAdjustmentTypeId": "SHIPPING_CHARGES"
      }
    ],
    "shipments": [
      {
        "shipmentId": "0001",
        "shipmentItems": [
          {
            "parentFacilityTypeId": "DISTRIBUTION_CENTER",
            "quantity": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Expected JSON**

```json
[
  {
    "Order_ID": "16487",
    "Shipment_ID": "0001"
  },
  {
    "Order_ID": "16488",
    "Amount": 25.95,
    "Shipment_ID": "0001"
  },
  {
    "Order_ID": "16489",
    "Shipment_ID": "0001"
  }
]
```

I have prepare the Jolt spec as per the requirements mentioned above.

**Jolt Spec**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "shipments": {
          "*": {
            "shipmentItems": {
              "*": {
                "parentFacilityTypeId": {
                  "DISTRIBUTION_CENTER": {
                    "#Y": "[&7].fulfilledFromWH"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "@": "[&]"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "fulfilledFromWH": "N"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "fulfilledFromWH": {
          "N": {
            "@(2,orderAdjustments)": {
              "*": {
                "orderAdjustmentTypeId": {
                  "SHIPPING_CHARGES": {
                    "@(2,amount)": "[&7].shippingAmount"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "@": "[&]"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "orderId": "[&1].Order_ID",
        "shippingAmount": "[&1].Amount",
        "shipments": {
          "*": {
            "shipmentId": "[&3].Shipment_ID"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I got the desired output by using the above spec, but need to know if there is another approach to achieve the expected output.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: But there are multiple `Amount`s ... Which one of them do you want to pick ?

Comment: where the orderAdjustmentTypeId = SHIPPING_CHARGES

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be checking out the existence of **`"DISTRIBUTION_CENTER"`** value within a **modify** transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "orderId": "@(1,orderId).&",
        "@shipments[0].shipmentId": "@(1,orderId).Shipment_ID",
        "*": { // level of both "orderAdjustments" and "shipments"
          "*": {
            "amount": "@(3,orderId).@(1,orderAdjustmentTypeId).&",
            "shipmentItems": {
              "*": {
                "parentFacilityTypeId": {
                  "DISTRIBUTION_CENTER": { "# ": "@(7,orderId).Amountt" } // a new parameter defined
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "~Amountt": "@(1,SHIPPING_CHARGES.amount)", // means if "Amount" does not exist or is null, then set it with the desired value 
        "Amount": ["=toDouble(@(1,Amountt))", null]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "orderId|Sh*": "[#2].&",
        "Amount": {
          "*": { // the null values vanish through this loop
            "@1": "[#4].&2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```